# Firebase FCM onLaunch code not running functions when clicking on notification

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM to deliver notifications that once clicked take the user to a specific page on the app. Currently, the onMessage and onResume functions work perfectly fine but on launch does not.

I include the

```
<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
<false/>
```

and

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
}
```

because I am also using flutter local notifications.

I have already tried removing these lines  but they do not make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the problem I had was that when the on launch code fires my app was loading other data and functions e.t.c when on the loading splash page. What I had to do was when on launch fires I saved the notification in a variable. Then I executed the code I wanted after the splash init was finished

```
onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> notification) async {
    print("onLaunch: $notification");

    ///Saving the notification to use once the rest of the initialising and 
    ///Loading is done
    launchNotification = notification;

},
```

Then once the loading and the initialising of other processes had finished I ran the ran this function

```
onLaunchFunction() async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100));
  Map tempNotification = launchNotification;
  if (launchNotification != null) {
    launchNotification = null;
    ///The rest of the function
  }
}
```

I added an a future delayed just to make sure that my code would run whilst the initialising. This may not be needed

Comment: Are you still using this way? Did you get to develop another (cleaner — if I can say so) way?

Comment: @MohammedAl-sadi I haven't changed it because it just works. There may be better ways I have not looked into any. Do tell me if you find any? Thanks

Comment: Thank you @GILO for your response. I just discovered today (After reading your answer) the ability of using SchedulerBinding. It callbacks any function after completing rendering the UI (read more about it, I am still poor at flutter). Here is a sample code:   SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
                (_) => YourFunctionComesHere());